# Creating a calculated field for my simple SQL 2008 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here's what the table looks like:

```
create table Shipping
(
ShippingId int primary key identity(1,1),
ProductId int foreign key references Product(ProductId),
LargoEnCm decimal(16,2),
AltoEnCm decimal(16,2),
AnchoEnCm decimal(16,2),
PesoKg decimal(16,2),
PesoVolumen decimal(16,2),
PesoFacturable decimal(16,2),
A decimal(16,2),
B decimal(16,2),
C decimal(16,2),
D decimal(16,2),
E decimal(16,2),
F decimal(16,2),
G decimal(16,2)
)
```

For example, the field `PesoVolumen` should be a calculated field from this:

```
(LargoEnCm * AltoEnCm * AnchoEnCm) / 6000
```

How would I declare this calculation so that everytime someone enters the data in the rows this field is automatically populated?

How about conditional statements? Does SQL support this?

For example, in `PesoFacturable` the value of either `PesoKg` or `PesoVolumen` would go into it, depending on which is bigger. An If statement would solve this, can I write this directly in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shipping]
(
    [ShippingId]        INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ProductId]         INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Product]([ProductId]),
    [LargoEnCm]         DECIMAL(16,2),
    [AltoEnCm]          DECIMAL(16,2),
    [AnchoEnCm]         DECIMAL(16,2),
    [PesoKg]            DECIMAL(16,2),
    [PesoFacturable]    AS CASE WHEN [PesoKg] > (([LargoEnCm] * [AltoEnCm] * [AnchoEnCm]) / 6000) THEN [PesoKg] ELSE (([LargoEnCm] * [AltoEnCm] * [AnchoEnCm]) / 6000) END,
    [A]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [B]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [C]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [D]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [E]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [F]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [G]                 DECIMAL(16,2),
    [PesoVolumen]       AS (([LargoEnCm] * [AltoEnCm] * [AnchoEnCm]) / 6000)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [documentation for computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx). You need something like this:

```
create table Shipping
(
ShippingId int primary key identity(1,1),
ProductId int foreign key references Product(ProductId),
LargoEnCm decimal(16,2),
AltoEnCm decimal(16,2),
AnchoEnCm decimal(16,2),
PesoKg decimal(16,2),
PesoFacturable decimal(16,2),
A decimal(16,2),
B decimal(16,2),
C decimal(16,2),
D decimal(16,2),
E decimal(16,2),
F decimal(16,2),
G decimal(16,2),
PesoVolumen AS (LargoEnCm * AltoEnCm * AnchoEnCm) / 6000
)
```

You can include most expressions as a computed column calculation, including [CASE statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).